# How can I find need words with xpath?

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to crawl a website,but I dont konw how to parse and find word.
The following is the website,I want to find "hello I'm here".

This is my xpath code:

```
//div[@class='sort_left']/p/strong/a/href/text()
```

Html part:

```
<div class="sort hottest_dishes1">
    <ul class="sort_title">
        <li class="current"><a href="/list_rest.php?a=75&s=1">按默认排序</a></li>
        <li class=""><a href="/list_rest.php?a=75&s=2">按人气排序</a></li>
    </ul>

    <ol class="sort_content">
        <li class="show">
            <div class="sort_yi">                              
                <div class="sort_left">
                    <p class="li_title">
                        <strong class="span_left ">
                            <a href="/rest/75/1879">hello I'm here<span class="restaurant_list_hot"></span></a>
                            <span> （川菜） </span>
                        </strong>
                        <span class="span_d_right3" title="馋嘴牛蛙特价只要9.9元，每单限点1份">馋嘴牛蛙特价9块9</span>
                    </p>
                    <p class="consume">
                        <strong>人均消费：</strong>
                        <b><span>¥70</span>元</b>
                        <a href="http://www.dianping.com/shop/2271520" target="_blank">看网友点评</a>
                    </p>
                    <p class="sign">
                        <strong>招牌菜：</strong>
                        <span>水煮鲶鱼 馋嘴牛蛙 酸梅汤 钵钵鸡 香辣土豆丝 毛血旺 香口猪手 ……</span>
                    </p> 
                </div>
                <div class="sort_right">
                    <a href="/rest/75/1879">看菜谱</a>
                </div>
                <div class="sort_all"  >
                    <strong>送达时间：</strong><span>60分钟</span>                                    
                </div>
            </div>
```

I use response.css in shell is right ,but in scrapy,it returns nothing,am I write the code wrong?
The following is my code:

```
def parse_torrent(self, response):
    torrent = TorrentItem()
    torrent['url'] = response.url
    torrent['name'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='sort_left']/p/strong/a[1]").extract()[1]
    torrent['description'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='list_content']/div/div/ol/li/div/div/p/strong[1]/following-sibling::span[1]").extract()
    torrent['size'] = response.xpath("//div[@id='list_content']/div/div/ol/li/div/div/p/span[1]").extract()
    return torrent
```

**strong text**

Comment: You are telling that you want `hello I'm here`, but you xpath refering to `href` element of a. Are you sure about what you are asking and what you want to reach?!

Comment: Just remove the `href` part from your xpath query.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see a `<div>` in your HTML excerpt which has an attribute with value `'list_content'` – so the `[@id='list_content']` predicate filters-out everything, whatever the rest of your XPath expression is. The result of the expression evaluation is an empty sequence.

**After the question edit:**

There is no `<href>` element in your HTML, so the `.../a/href` subexpression selects nothing.
`href` is an attribute of `<a>` – use `.../a/@href` instead to proces the `href` attribute contents.

However if you still want to find the 'hello I'm here' text, then you need to reach the `<a>` element contents – use `.../a/text()`.

Comment: the html is not complete,and I changed a similiar xpath.

Answer (score 0):

This can be an example of what you need to do:

```
def parse_torrent(self, response):
    print response.xpath('//div[@class="sort_left"]/p/strong/a/text()').extract()[0]
```

output:

```
2014-12-19 10:58:28+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: skema_crawler)
2014-12-19 10:58:28+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2014-12-19 10:58:28+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'skema_crawler.spiders', 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['skema_crawler.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'skema_crawler'}
2014-12-19 10:58:28+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, RetryMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [linkedin] INFO: Spider opened
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [linkedin] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [linkedin] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET file:///C:/1.html> (referer: None)
hello I'm here
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [linkedin] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [linkedin] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
        {'downloader/request_bytes': 232,
         'downloader/request_count': 1,
         'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
         'downloader/response_bytes': 1599,
         'downloader/response_count': 1,
         'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
         'finish_reason': 'finished',
         'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 19, 9, 58, 29, 241000),
         'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
         'log_count/INFO': 7,
         'response_received_count': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued': 1,
         'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued': 1,
         'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 1,
         'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 12, 19, 9, 58, 29, 213000)}
2014-12-19 10:58:29+0100 [linkedin] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

you can see that `hello I'm here` appeared.

You are referring to

`response.xpath("//div[@class='sort_left']/p/strong/a[1]").extract()[1]`

you need to add text() to your xpath and as your `a` has a `span` inside, you need to get the element [0] and not [1]. So then you need to change it to

`response.xpath("//div[@class='sort_left']/p/strong/a/text()").extract()[0]`

Answer (score 0):

I personally find css selectors much easier than using xpath for locating content. For the response object that you get on crawling the given document, why don't you try `response.css('p[class="li_title"] a::text')[0].extract()`.

(I tested it and it works in scrapy shell. The output: `u"hello I'm here"`)

Comment: I use css in shell is right ,but in scrapy ,it return nothing.

Comment: @leisurem - if it works in the shell, it should too in the spider. What's the exact error that you're getting? Have you tried printing/storing the result?